# Grammar control disabled on certain rows

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

Dunno why but on my document, on certain rows, automatic orthographic control is disabled.
Is there a way to enable it on all the document?

Orthography is the methodology of writing a language. It includes rules of spelling, hyphenation, capitalization, word breaks, emphasis, and punctuation.

Comment: In Word, what is *"automatic ortographic control"*? I am unable to find anything about this. Please explain better.

Answer (score 2):

1. Highlight all content within your document (Ctrl+A).
2. Under the "Review" tab click "Select Language".
3. Check and then Uncheck "Do not check spelling or grammar".
4. Click Ok